# Ratio of segments in a regular hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCDEF$ be a regular hexagon of side $2$.
 On the segments $AC$ and $CE$ we select the points $M,N$ such that $$\frac{AM}{AC} = \frac{CN}{CE} = k. $$

Further the problem states that the points $B,N,M$ are collinear and asks to find $k$.

No matter what I try I just can't find $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If $B,M,N$ are collinear then $[BCN]=[BCM]+[CMN]$. Since $AC=2\sqrt{3}$ and $\widehat{ACB}=30^\circ, \widehat{ACE}=60^\circ$, that leads to

$$  2k =  (1-k) + 3 k(1-k) $$
hence $k=\color{blue}{\large\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$, corresponding to $BC=CN$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got from [BCN]=[BCM]+[CMN] to 2k=(1−k)+3k(1−k)

Comment: @AlexRosu: $$ 2 [BCN]= BC\cdot CN\cdot \sin\widehat{BCN} $$ and so on.